# direction and location

Tags: modal-verb, conjugation

I came across this sentence

> unser Auto muss in die Werkstatt

which obviously implies direction here. My sense tells me that if we are talking about location instead of direction, we should add 'sein', i.e.

> unser Auto muss in der Werkstatt sein

So is it a rule that we don't need 'sein' for direction but need 'sein' for location?

Answer (score 1):

> Unser Auto muss in die Werkstatt.

This is a very idiomatic use of modals as full verbs. It implies a matching verb. If you use it with a direction, you need to think of a verb that needs a direction e.g. bringen.

> Unser Auto muss in die Werkstatt *gebracht werden.*

(Passive voice is needed because the car won't move by itself. Despite being an *auto*mobile. How odd.)

---

> Unser Auto muss in der Werkstatt sein.

This is also correct but it means a very different thing. It's another very idiomatic use of modals. The *muss* modal indicates a very strong assumption. So this is a variant of Futur I tense

> Unser Auto wird in der Werkstatt sein.

And yeah, *sein* requires a location.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that English does not allow this; an English modal verb *must* be followed by an infinitive. In German, if it's a common, flavorless verb that can be filled in by context then it can be dropped using the power of ellipsis. I'd say dropping the final verb is actually preferred in spoken German when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your second sentence is correct but unidiomatic. *Sein* enforces a location in your context, but there are by far better examples as:

> Das Auto steht in der Werkstatt.

> Ich muss um 8:30 Uhr in Berlin sein.

I remmend [wechselpraeposition](/questions/tagged/wechselpraeposition) for **many** related questions.